Having trouble reading a csv file with embedded commas in some values
I am using clean dataset from this kaggle, for a school project and i have to write code in c++ that sorts the data and allows me to run statistical analysis on the data.
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/elvinrustam/ebay-laptops-and-netbooks-sales/data
I've done a lot of trial and error but i cant seem to figure out how to ignore the commas and random quotes within the data using c++. I try storing the the data from each heading to a vector so that i can do operations on the data after but when i print the data i see that there is other data getting mixed up in the data sets and randoms commas, brackets, long pieces of text, etc.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <set>

std::vector<std::string> parseCSVLine(const std::string& line) {
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    std::string cell;
    bool inQuotes = false;
    bool inBulletPoint = false; // New flag to track when we're within a bullet point
    for (auto it = line.begin(); it != line.end(); ++it) {
        const char nextChar = *it;

        // Check for bullet points
        if (!inQuotes && *it == '•') {
            inBulletPoint = true; // We're now inside a bullet point
            cell += nextChar; // Add the bullet point character to the cell
            continue;
        }

        // If we're in a bullet point, check for the end of the line or a comma (end of cell)
        if (inBulletPoint && (nextChar == ',' || it == line.end() - 1)) {
            inBulletPoint = false; // Exiting bullet point mode
            if (nextChar != ',') {
                cell += nextChar; // Ensure last character is included if not a comma
            }
            result.push_back(cell);
            cell.clear();
            continue;
        }
        else if (inBulletPoint) {
            // Simply add the character to the cell without interpreting it
            cell += nextChar;
            continue;
        }

        // Handle quotes (outside of bullet points)
        if (nextChar == '"') {
            if (inQuotes && (it + 1 != line.end()) && (*(it + 1) == '"')) {
                cell += nextChar; // Add a single quote to the cell value
                ++it; // Skip the next quote
            }
            else {
                inQuotes = !inQuotes;
            }
        }
        else if (nextChar == ',' && !inQuotes) {
            result.push_back(cell);
            cell.clear();
        }
        else {
            cell += nextChar;
        }
    }
    // Only check the last character if the line is not empty
    if (!cell.empty() || (!line.empty() && line.back() == ',')) {
        result.push_back(cell);
    }


    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::string filePath = "insert file path here";
    std::ifstream file(filePath);
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file: " << filePath << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> headers;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> columnData;

    if (getline(file, line)) {
        headers = parseCSVLine(line);
        columnData.resize(headers.size());
    }

    while (getline(file, line)) {
        auto data = parseCSVLine(line);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < data.size() && i < columnData.size(); ++i) {
            columnData[i].push_back(data[i]);
        }
    }

    file.close();

    //// Example output: Printing unique values for each heading for verification
    //for (size_t i = 0; i < headers.size(); ++i) {
    //    std::set<std::string> uniqueValues(columnData[i].begin(), columnData[i].end());
    //    std::cout << "Heading: " << headers[i] << " - Unique Values: " << uniqueValues.size() << std::endl;
    //    for (const auto& value : uniqueValues) {
    //        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    //    }
    //    std::cout << std::endl;
    //}


    // Make sure to define and fill 'columnData' and 'headers' as per your CSV parsing logic before this snippet

    // Here, the index is set to 2 since vector indices are 0-based and we want the third column (heading 3)
    size_t index = 2;

    // Check if the index is within the bounds of the 'columnData' vector
    if (index < columnData.size()) {
        std::cout << "Values under Heading 3 (" << headers[index] << "):" << std::endl;

        // Iterate over the vector at the given index and print each value
        for (const auto& value : columnData[index]) {
            std::cout << value << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Index out of range. The columnData does not have a heading 3." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


Are you asking for help sorting the data or just reading the data correctly? You may find something that will help with reading the data here How can I read and parse CSV files in C++?

what is in the file? Whats output of your code? What should it be instead? Can you read and parse a single line without errors?

CSV isn't as simple as most folk expect. As soon as you get embedded commas inside a value, you need to use a real parser. iostream primatives alone are not sufficient. Use a library if you can. If you can't and just have to deal with quotes and nasty stuff potentially lurking between the quotes a state machine (with two states: gathering quote and normal reading) may be enough.

You have to be able to account for a comma within a string: "hi, world".  The std::getline(text, ',') function would stop after "hi,", which is not correct.

I've done a lot of trial and error but i cant seem to figure out how to ignore the commas and random quotes within the data using c++. So it seems the problem is not the sorting it's reading the CSV file in the first place.

In the general case scanning csv is non trivial. But looking at this specific data it obeys a couple of rules. There are no escaped characters. If text is quoted then the open quote immediately follows a comma and the close quote is immediately followed by a comma. So that should make it easier.

All of these comments were very helpful in figuring out my problems, thank you all so much!

BTW, the reason for my comment above and modification of your question title is I think the new question title better fits the purpose of this Q&A and could help future readers. While your larger problem / assignment had to do with sorting the focus of this question is the reading part and that is a better StackOveflow question because it focuses on a single issue which future readers may have. Notice I mentioned future readers twice above. The #1 goal of a Q&A at StackOverflow is to help future readers solve the same problem.

To simplify the answer assumes.

There are no escape characters.
That the code only uses double quotes (")
That double quotes are the first character and last character in a cell.
=> open is first character on the line or first character after comma.
=> close is last character on the line or immediately followed by comma.
Not all cells use quotes but all cells that have commas use quotes.

A quick scan of the OA input data seem to indicate thses factors hold. But if the data changes you will need to revervirify.
Note: Scanning a generic CSV these conditions may not hold and you should use a real parser. But a well-behaved CSV file with these conditions this should suffice.

I would split this into two problems.

Scanning a Line
Scanning a Value (Cell).

So I would do it like this:
Note: Not code reviewed, so may have some mistakes. Please validate with tests.
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

struct Value
{
    std::string     value;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Value const& data)
    {
        s << data.value;
        return s;
    }
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, Value& data)
    {
        // assumes cell ends with a ',' or eof
        // Will remove the trailing ',' from the stream but not include it in the data
        // If cell is quoted (") then removes quotes does not add them to the data.
        // Assumes quotes are first and last character in cell.

        char peek = s.peek();
        if (peek != '"') {
            std::getline(s, data.value, ',');   // drops trailing comma
        }
        else {
            char get1 = s.get();                // gets leading quote
            std::getline(s, data.value, '"');  // drops tailing quote
            char get2 = s.get();                // gets trailing comma
        }
        return s;
    }
};
struct Line
{
    std::vector<Value>        values;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Line const& data)
    {
        for (auto const& v: data.values) {
            s << v << ",";
        }
        return s;
    }
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, Line& data)
    {
        // assumes we can get a line of data with std::getline
        // All the data is in chunks of Value.

        std::string line;
        if (std::getline(s, line)) {

            std::stringstream   lineStream(std::move(line));
            std::vector<Value>  tmp{std::istream_iterator<Value>{lineStream}, std::istream_iterator<Value>{}};
            data.values = std::move(tmp);
        }
        return s;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::ifstream   csv("EbayPcLaptopsAndNetbooksUnclean.csv");

    Line    line;
    int     count = 0;
    int     lineSizeCount[1000] = {0};
    while(csv >> line) {
        ++count;
        ++lineSizeCount[line.values.size()];
    }
    std::cout << "Lines: " << count << "\n";
    for (int loop = 0; loop < 1000; ++loop) {
        if (lineSizeCount[loop] != 0) {
            std::cout << "  Size: " << loop << " => " << lineSizeCount[loop] << "\n";
        }
    }
}


I based my reading of the csv off of this and i managed to finally get it to work, thank you so much
